# Clicking on Feature Commands doesn't work Icinga2 2.7.1

Tags: icinga2

I'm logged into an Icinga master (Icingaweb2 http interface) as an administrator with "Allow everything (*)" permissions yet when I try to disable passive checks by clicking the Passive Checks checkbox the web interface throws an error:

icinga2: Can't send external Icinga command: 404 No objects found.

```
#0 /usr/share/icingaweb2/modules/monitoring/application/forms/Command/Object/ToggleObjectFeaturesCommandForm.php(169): Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Command\Transport\CommandTransport->send(Object(Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Command\Object\ToggleObjectFeatureCommand))
#1 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Web/Form.php(1158): Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Forms\Command\Object\ToggleObjectFeaturesCommandForm->onSuccess()
#2 /usr/share/icingaweb2/modules/monitoring/library/Monitoring/Web/Controller/MonitoredObjectController.php(85): Icinga\Web\Form->handleRequest()
#3 /usr/share/icingaweb2/modules/monitoring/application/controllers/HostController.php(61): Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Web\Controller\MonitoredObjectController->showAction()
#4 /usr/share/icingaweb2/library/vendor/Zend/Controller/Action.php(507): Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Controllers\HostController->showAction()
#5 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Web/Controller/Dispatcher.php(76): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('showAction')
#6 /usr/share/icingaweb2/library/vendor/Zend/Controller/Front.php(937): Icinga\Web\Controller\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Icinga\Web\Request), Object(Icinga\Web\Response))
#7 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Application/Web.php(389): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(Object(Icinga\Web\Request), Object(Icinga\Web\Response))
#8 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Application/webrouter.php(109): Icinga\Application\Web->dispatch()
#9 /usr/share/icingaweb2/public/index.php(4): require_once('/usr/share/php/...')
#10 {main}
```

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: I have not found a solution. This is the first time I have tried to set up Icinga2 without zones, i.e. without any satellites. This week I upgraded to Icinga 2.8.1 and icingaweb2 2.5.1 but I get the same error when I try to acknowledge an alert.